# How to stop fixed page background from jumping on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a full page height and width background image to a page that is designed to cover the who back of the viewport that also adapts to the size of the viewport. This work brilliantly on desktop - however on mobile (both iPhone and Android) when the address bar and navigation bars are hidden (default browser behavior) as you scroll down the background image jumps (as seen below):

https://ibb.co/7jWLqWh

The code I'm using for this is:

HTML:

```
<div id="bg">
  <img src="../../assets/landing-page/bg.png" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bg {
      position: fixed; 
      top: -32%; 
      left: -90%; 
      width: 200%; 
      height: 200%;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    #bg img {
        position: absolute; 
        top: 0; 
        left: 0; 
        right: 0; 
        bottom: 0; 
        margin: auto; 
        min-width: 50%;
        min-height: 50%;
        opacity: 0.75;
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps instead of aligning it to the edges, centering it could solve it. It would at least ease the sudden offset a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As % values are being used, when there is suddenly more space because a browser bar has disappeared, the size suddenly jumps.

To get round this problem the suppliers decided to fix the vh height unit. While this can cause other problems, like full height 100vh divs having the bottom cut off when a website is entered, it was designed to help mitigate the sort of scrolling-jump problem seen here.

Suggestion is that you try defining the heights in vh units rather than %s to see if that fixes things.